# get data with ajax, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I have this code to work with:

```
<div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="content">
                <form id="registerForm" action="/register" method="post" data-ajax="false" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="rUIdInput">Email:</label>
                            <input name="<%=User.USER_ID%>" id="rUIdInput" value="" type="email" placeholder="your.mail@abc.com" /> 
                            <label for="rUPwInput">Password:</label>
                            <input name="<%=BasicAuthRedirectServlet.PASSWORD%>" id="rUpwInput" value="" type="password" placeholder="Your password" />
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" data-theme="b">Register</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When I click the register button and type on some values and hit register, I get back a JSON object. I m not sure how to get a handle on this JSON object

THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hopefully assume that you need to `POST` the data of the form to `/register`. If that is the case, then this is what you need to follow. You have already said that the button is:

```
<button type="submit" data-theme="b">Register</button>
```

Using jQuery (or jQM), you can do this:

1. Give an `ID` to the button and the form.

   ```
   <form id="registerFrm" action="/register" method="post" data-ajax="false" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">

   <button type="submit" data-theme="b" id="registerBtn">Register</button>
   ```
2. Next is setting the **handler** for the button action.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#registerBtn").click(function () {
           $.ajax({
               url: $("#registerFrm").attr("action"),
               data: $("#registerFrm").serialize(),
               type: "POST",
               success: function (data) {
                   alert(data);
               }
           })
       });
   });
   ```

Say if this worked for you.

Comment: when I press submit I get a JSON object back. I just dont know how to get a handle on this object.

Comment: @MJB I just updated that part. :) Once you get JSON, what do you wanna do?

Comment: It actually did work then I set data-ajax = true